# Can't show data on spinner? throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, spinner

can anyone tell wats wrong in this code... I put code bellow.

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.displayCategory();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY };

    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.choose_category);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, from, to);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
```

MyAdapter class having following code

```
public Cursor displayCategory() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CATEGORY};          
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYCATEGORY_TABLE, columns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
```

Null pointer Exception. How to avoid it.
This is the error on log cat

```
 09-09 15:49:16.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting  due to uncaught exception
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mpt.receiptor/com.android.mpt.receiptor.SearchReceipt}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at com.android.mpt.receiptor.SQLiteAdapter.displayCategory(SQLiteAdapter.java:135)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at com.android.mpt.receiptor.SearchReceipt.onCreate(SearchReceipt.java:96)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-09 15:49:16.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

Pls someone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How to avoid it." ... don't use `SomeObject obj = functionThatReturnsNull(); obj.DoSmthing();`

Comment: `SomeObject obj = functionThatReturnsNull(); if(obj != null) { obj.DoSmthing(); }` or check why `functionThatReturnsNull()` returns null ... well reading/analyzing the code is far more difficult than just copy/paste ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in this line:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYCATEGORY_TABLE, columns,  
            null, null, null, null, null);
```

that `sqLiteDatabase` is null - make sure it is initialised in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: or mCategory is null `mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.choose_category);` he didn't say where exaclly error occur

Comment: `blablabla(SearchReceipt.java:96)` <= you know what it means ?

Comment: @Selvin see the log buddy. Culprit is displayCategory()

Answer (score 1):

why cant you put a breakpoint in the displayCategory() method? null pointer exceptions are quite easy to find.As Cjk has pointed out, sqlitedatabase is unitialised. Debugging will help you find and solve issues before you lose much of your time..